# How to change Bootstrap 3 button onclick css style

Tags: css, onclick, twitter-bootstrap-3

when I click on a Bootstrap button, a csss is applied while the mouse button is clicked. This is also visible when the mouse button is hold pressed over a bootstrap button.

I need to change that style, but I can't find it using inspect element. How can I find what style is applied and how can I change it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see the styles attached to :hover and other pseudo classes in firebug and the chrome debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767278/how-can-i-see-the-styles-attached-to-hover-and-other-pseudo-classes-in-firebug)

Comment: While that will potentially expose the issue, I feel like Johann Dyck's answer is a much more straightforward answer to the question in the context asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem the other week. If you're using chrome, open inspect element, code highlight the button, right click, select Force Element State, select :focus. This will show you the CSS code that you need to alter.

Answer (score 3):

Having an issue with this myself until I applied the style to `.btn-default:active:focus`

Comment: Was actually about to flame this answer... however this astonishingly works! Somehow the combination of both `:active:hover` works in the Bootstrap 3 context. They don't seem to work individually. Thanks Johann!

Comment: Glad you found it useful! Honestly, I don't even remember what project I used that on.